# How to intuitively explain the maths behind overdispersion?

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, intuition, overdispersion, deviance

I understand that overdispersion indicates extra, unexplained variation in the response than would be expected based on the statistical model of choice. And that the residual deviance is a measure of goodness of fit.

But I don't have an intuition behind why the ratio of residual deviance to residual degrees of freedom gives a measure of overdispersion.

Comment: The response on this thread makes a few suggestions wrt your query... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318813/increase-difference-between-mean-and-median